# Obstacle inflation in costmap_2d

Tags: ros

I an currently using map_server from a .png file to test some planning algorithms but I now want to see the obstacles inflated in accordance with the robot radius. For this, I tried to use "costmap_2d" with static map.
This is what I have managed to put together thus far -

```
<launch>
<node name="transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map base_frame 10" />
<node name="mapServer" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find mapwork)/img/map.yaml" />
<node pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_markers" name="voxel_visualizer">
<remap from="voxel_grid" to="costmap/voxel_grid"/>
</node>
<node name="costmap_node" pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_node" ns="costmap"/>
<rosparam file="$(find mapwork)/img/gcp.yaml" command="load" />
<node name="visualizer" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

And the .yaml file (gcp.yaml):

```
inflation_radius: 1.0
cost_scaling_factor: 0.2
robot_radius: 0.5
```

There is no change in the map with/without the costmap_2d package, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your configuration:

1. costmap_2d expects a tf between frames `map` and `base_link`, not `base_frame`. So either change the name in tf to `base_link` or change the name the costmap expects, using the `robot_base_frame` parameter.
2. Parameters have to be loaded into the namespace of the costmap node, otherwise they will not be used.
3. Parameter `static_map` has to be set to true, otherwise the costmap will not consider the map you are loading.

The following should work:

**Launch file**

```xml
<launch>
  <node name="transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map base_link 10" />
  <node name="mapServer" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find mapwork)/img/map.yaml" />
  <node pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_markers" name="voxel_visualizer">
    <remap from="voxel_grid" to="costmap/voxel_grid"/>
  </node>
  <node name="costmap_node" pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_node">
    <rosparam file="$(find mapwork)/img/gcp.yaml" command="load" ns="costmap" />
  </node>
  <node name="visualizer" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

*Changes made: rename base_frame to base_link, load parameters inside the costmap `<node>`, move `ns="costmap"` from `<node>` to `<rosparam>`.*

**Costmap configuration (gcp.yaml)**

```
static_map: true
inflation_radius: 1.0
cost_scaling_factor: 0.2
robot_radius: 0.5
```

*Changes made: added `static_map`.*

Note, that **this will not change the map** published on topic /map but will publish the inflated map on topic /costmap_node/costmap/costmap.